# ReferenceError: XXXXXXX is not defined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am getting the values from Ajax and looping it to get the data as follows

```
$.each(dataar, function(index, el) {
    $('#show'+index).html('<a href="#" onclick="viewvideo('+el['youtube_id']+');"><img width="100" height="100" src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/'+el['youtube_id']+'/0.jpg" /></a>');
 });


function viewvideo(id)
    {
        alert(id);
    }
```

But the problem is from function `viewvideo()` i cannot get the passed value for ID

Comment: How did you use `viewvideo` ? I don't see any reference

Comment: It alerts undefined, or it alerts null or it doesn't alert at all etc? Try being more specific about the issue

Comment: alert el['youtube_id'] in the function $.each and check whether it contains value or not

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotation marks:

```
'... onclick="viewvideo(\''+el['youtube_id']+'\');" ...'
//                      ^^                    ^^
```

Otherwise, the generated code tries to pass a variable

```
onclick="viewvideo(foo);"
```

instead of a string

```
onclick="viewvideo('foo');"
```

---

You can easily figure this out on your own if you look at the generated elements and their attributes in the inspector.

And the better solution which avoids such problems is to create **DOM elements** instead of HTML and bind the event handlers with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks a lot this work out fine save a lot of time thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

Your not escaping your "  '  " and misses your quotation marks for a string. in the viewVideo call. Try this

```
onclick="viewvideo("'+el["youtube_id"]+'");"
```

or

```
onclick="viewvideo("'+el[\'youtube_id\']+'");"
```